# Perl encrypting STDIN passwords

Tags: linux, perl, security, unix, encryption

I'm producing a Perl module that provides an OO interface for a 3rd party API. I want to capture and store the user's password in an encrypted format before it is transmitted to the 3rd party API. The module is intended to be run on UNIX-based systems only.

I've produced the following script that performs the capture function - is this correct in the sense that it only stores the password variable in an encrypted format? I'm concerned that the password may be available in memory elsewhere (e.g. under $_ although $_ is undef).

NB. I'm using STDIN rather than @ARGV with the assumption that the OS will not log the entry or include the password in the process name. I'm using a substitute regex rather than chomp so that the input would not have to be stored in a temporary non-encrypted variable. I'm also assuming that it is not possible to be completely secure in the sense that input capture software could still capture the user's input.

Thanks in advance

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::CBC;
use 5.14.0;

print 'Please enter your password: ';
system('tty -echo');
my $key = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes(56);
my $iv  = Crypt::CBC->random_bytes(8);
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-key    => $key,
                             -cipher => 'Blowfish',
                             -salt   => 1,
                             );
my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt(<STDIN> =~ s/\n$//r);
system('tty echo');
```

Comment: you should probably check for password length, and what does `/r` stands for?

Comment: @mpapec `/r` is non-destructive substitution introduced in perl 5.14 (see perlop) - it does not modify string in place but returns a modified copy instead (very handy feature).

Comment: Who are you trying to protect this from?  If someone can peek at your process memory to read the encrypted password, you have to assume they can also read the key and your program source.  Reading the password from stdin rather than as a command line argument will protect from casual browsers, and is probably the best you can expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's tough.

Run your encrypting code as a separate process, child of the main code, which process reads from STDIN and returns the encrypted password (and perhaps key).  In that way, the code using your module will itself never hold the plaintext in memory.

Sure, tracing and memory inspection (and *system* memory inspection after process death) of the child helper will reveal the plaintext.  The same techniques will reveal key and ciphertext read from a child helper, too.  However, if the scenario against which you wish to defend is accidental retention of the plaintext in your process — in a complex object or a closure or I-didn't-know-a-temp-var-was-allocated-there — then do the work in a dedicated, short-lived process.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ strace perl -E '<STDIN>'
.... scroll, scroll, scroll ....
read(0, 
... type, type, type ....
"secret\n", 4096)               = 7
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

I don't think that you can prevent someone with sufficient access rights from peeking inside your system calls or memory.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're implementing the [Password Anti-pattern](http://designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns/The_Password_Anti-Pattern). That's a terrible idea - it teaches users to be phished. Please don't do that. You should look at using [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) instead.

Comment: Please enlighten me how I can use OAuth on command line applications? Especially if the API which OP is wrapping expects an encrypted *password*?

Comment: It's certainly possible (I have command line Twitter programs which use OAuth) but setting up the OAuth initially can be a little complex and will need a browser. See https://github.com/davorg/localtwits/blob/master/build.pl for an example. But even if it was impossible, that's not an excuse for encouraging users to break the first rule of internet security - Never share a password with a third party.

Comment: Thanks - using this approach would remove a lot of security risks. I realise this was not in my post, however I need to generate an XML template which is sent via https to the 3rd party API. If the 3rd party API does not support OAutho explicitly, can I still use it to solve this problem?

Comment: You can only use OAuth with services that support OAuth. But you should never ask a user to give you their password for another service.

Comment: Following that dictum this module could not be written as all the API services require an authenticated session.

Comment: @Sillymoose: That sounds likely. But what's more important to you? Writing this service or teaching users that internet password security is unimportant? You might find my blog post on the subject interesting - http://blog.dave.org.uk/2012/03/internet-security-rule-one.html